# Why do I always get this error?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sqlcommand

Here is my code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
con.Open();

SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
sqlCmd.Connection = con;
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ChheckIn VALUES 
(rakmsheek,tare5sheek,esmsa7bsheek,mablgh,hesab,esmel7sab,mla7zat) (" + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value + ", " + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value + "," + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value + ", " + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column4"].Value + ", " + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column5"].Value + ", " + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value + ", " + 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column7"].Value + ",);";


    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtkX8.png]

I want get data from my datagridview into table `CheckIn`.

I get error shown in the attached screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem 1:** you have added extra comma at the end of the INSERT INTO statement.
**Solution 1:**: Remove extra `comma` `(,)` at the end of the `INSERT INTO` Statement

Note : enclose all your `VARCHAR/NVARCHAR (String)` types inside `single quotes`

Example:

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tablename(name) VALUES('yourname');
```

Try This:

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ChheckIn (rakmsheek,tare5sheek,esmsa7bsheek,mablgh,hesab,esmel7sab,mla7zat) VALUES (" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value + "," + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column4"].Value + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column5"].Value + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column7"].Value + ");";
```

**Problem 2:** You misused/combined both Column Names and Values.

**Solution 2 :**  you need to use proper syntax.

```
 sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ChheckIn(rakmsheek,tare5sheek,esmsa7bsheek,mablgh,hesab,esmel7sab,mla7zat) VALUES (" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value + "," + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column4"].Value + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column5"].Value + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column7"].Value + ");";
```

**Problem 3/Suggestion :** Your query is open to SQL Injection attacks.

**Solution 3:** use `Parameterised queries` to avoid `sql injection attacks`.

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ChheckIn(rakmsheek,tare5sheek,esmsa7bsheek,mablgh,hesab,esmel7sab,mla7zat)     
VALUES(@rakmsheek,@tare5sheek,@esmsa7bsheek,@mablgh,@hesab,@esmel7sab,@mla7zat)";  

sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rakmsheek",dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value); 
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tare5sheek",dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value); 
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@esmsa7bsheek",dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value); 
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mablgh",dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column4"].Value); 
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hesab",dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column5"].Value);   
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@esmel7sab",dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value);
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mla7zat",dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column7"].Value);
```

Comment: @user3119262: enclose all your string type columns insdie the single quotes. check my edited answer.

Comment: @user3119262: your syntax is wrong , Please check my edited answer with `solution2`

Comment: Better yet: use **parametrized queries**! Then you don't have any issues with quotes and all those thorny troubles..... and you're protected from SQL injection attacks, too!

Comment: @user3119262: check my `solution 3` with `parameterised queries`.

Comment: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManage why this !?

Comment: i making my primarykey auto identify may that the problem ?

Comment: you sould not add IDENTITY columns in INSERT INTO statement, is `rakmsheek`  your primary column?

Comment: @user3119262: then it should not be a problem, try `solution 3`

Comment: bro i really Thanks to you :)

Comment: if u not we can speak at skype mohamed_koko_a